# TFT LCD ILI9486 and STM32

Tags: stm32, lcd

I bought a [TFT LCD Touch Screen Module ILI9486](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001840965760.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27426c37Hx8sfl) from AliExpress.

I followed the instructions from this video [Interface TFT display with STM32 in parallel mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTeNyY_g5i0&ab_channel=ControllersTech)

I found the [TFT LCD Specification](https://www.displayfuture.com/Display/datasheet/controller/ILI9486L.pdf) for this screen

Then, I am trying to get the Screen ID with this code:

```
uint16_t readID(void)
{
uint16_t ret;
uint32_t ID;
uint32_t ID4;
uint8_t msb;

ret  = readReg(0,0);        //  forces a reset() if called before begin()
ret  = readReg(1,0);        //  Soft reset
ID   = readReg32(0x04);     //  Read ID  1er: dummy, 2nd ID manuf
ID4  = readReg32(0xD3);     //  Read ID4 1er: dummy, 2nd IC version
msb = ID4 >> 8;
if (msb == 0x93 || msb == 0x94 || msb == 0x98 || msb == 0x77 || msb == 0x16)
    return ret;             //0x9488, 9486, 9340, 9341, 7796
...
}
```

The values returns are:
ID = 0x85858585
ID4= 0x939b9b9b
I was expected 0x9486 inside ID or ID4.

I used a STM32F103C8

Is there something wrong with my code?